# Iterate over hashref Template Toolkit

Tags: template-toolkit

The data that I'm passing to the template is as follows:

This is the 'tickets' hashref used in the following foreach:

```
$VAR1 = {
    '1234' => {'request_time' => '1405392890', 'id' => '1234'},
    '9993' => {'request_time' => '1485035309', 'id' => '9993'}
};
```

I am doing the following:

```
[% FOREACH ticket IN tickets %]
    <td>[% ticket.request_time %]</td>
    <td>[% ticket.id %]</td>
[% END -%]
```

But this doesn't seem to display anything. Could someone point out where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to be careful that TT doesn't treat a numeric hash-key as an array-element reference. If there's a risk of confusion (or if you have a clash between hash-keys and vmethod names), then the vmethod `item()` is particularly useful:

```
[% FOREACH ticket IN tickets.keys.nsort %]
    <td>[% tickets.item(ticket).request_time %]</td>
    <td>[% ticket %]</td>
[% END -%]
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware you had to use the 'keys' vmethod:

```
[% FOREACH ticket IN tickets.keys %]
    <td>[% tickets.$ticket.request_time %]</td>
    <td>[% tickets.$ticket.id %]</td>
[% END -%]
```